# Replacement rules for Power, Times and Ordered Objects

Tags: replacement

I'm trying to replace products of functions (with or without powers) that may not be found together in expressions.

For example, I want to take `Spaa[1, 2] Spbb[2, 1] -> -Spaa[1, 3] Spbb[3, 1]` in every expression.

However, my expressions might look like

```
 Spaa[1, 2]^2 Spaa[2, 3]^2 Spbb[2, 1]^3
```

How do I replace something like this? I have tried using

```
% /. Times[___, Spaa[1, 3], ___, Spbb[3, 1]] -> -Spaa[1, 2] Spbb[2, 1]
```

Which works for some expressions, but not others, and doesn't include the powers.

Comment: what is desired result for the input `Spaa[1,2]^2 Spaa[2,3]^2 Spbb[2,1]^3`?

Comment: `Spaa[1, 2]^2  Spaa[2, 3]^2 Spbb[2, 1]^3 /. 
 Times[a___, Spaa[1, 2]^b_., c___, 
   Spbb[2, 1]^d_.] :> -a Spaa[1, 3]^b c   Spbb[3, 1]^d`?

Comment: `PolynomialReduce` can be used for this. `In[268]:= 
PolynomialReduce[Spaa[1, 2]^2 Spaa[2, 3]^2 Spbb[2, 1]^3, 
  Spaa[1, 2] Spbb[2, 1] - (-Spaa[1, 3] Spbb[3, 1]), {Spaa[1, 2], 
   Spbb[2, 1], Spaa[1, 3], Spbb[3, 1]}][[2]]

Out[268]= Spaa[1, 3]^2 Spaa[2, 3]^2 Spbb[2, 1] Spbb[3, 1]^2`

Answer (score 1):

`PolynomialReduce` is useful for this.

```
In[1587]:= 
PolynomialReduce[Spaa[1, 2]^2 Spaa[2, 3]^2 Spbb[2, 1]^3, 
  Spaa[1, 2] Spbb[2, 1] - (-Spaa[1, 3] Spbb[3, 1]), {Spaa[1, 2], 
   Spbb[2, 1], Spaa[1, 3], Spbb[3, 1]}][[2]]

(* Out[1587]= Spaa[1, 3]^2 Spaa[2, 3]^2 Spbb[2, 1] Spbb[3, 1]^2 *)
```

Comment: Would you be able to comment [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/196905/12)? (You commented on related topics multiple times.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to treat separately the cases with powers and the cases without powers. This is because patterns match the form of the expression and
`Times[Power[a,n],Power[b,n]]` does not contain anywhere the expression `Times[a,b]`. I think the following solution might fork for you:

```
r = {Spaa[1, 2]^n_ Spbb[2, 1]^m_ :> (-Spaa[1, 3] Spbb[3, 1])^# Spaa[1, 2]^(n - #) Spbb[2, 1]^(m - #) &@Min[n, m], Spaa[1,2]Spbb[2,1] -> -Spaa[1,3]Spbb[3,1]};
```

And then do `expr/.r` to any expression `expr` to which you want to apply the rule.

The rule you defined in the question, namely

```
Times[___, Spaa[1, 2], ___, Spbb[2, 1]] -> -Spaa[1, 3] Spbb[3, 1]
```

(I'm assuming you mistakenly flipped 2 and 3), does not help because `Times` has attributes `Flat` so all its subsequences are assumed to be wrapped by `Times` for the purpose of pattern matching. Let me be clearer: for any function `f` so that `Attributes[f]` contains `{Flat}` this happens

```
 In[1]:= f[a,b,c,d]/.f[b,c]->something
Out[1]:= f[a,something,d]
```

Moreover it has attribute `Orderless`, so the blank in the middle is not needed. Because of these reasons the blanks actually never match anything, if it were otherwise whatever is matched by them would not appear in the r.h.s. (which is not what you wanted I assume).

Comment: You don't need to treat the case without power separately because `Power` is also `OneIdentity`. Try this: `a*b /. a_^n_.*b_^m_. :> {{a, n}, {b, n}}`.

Comment: You are right, I discovered this too after I published the answer, I should have edited it. But I don't agree with your explanation when you say that this is because `Power` is `OneIdentity`. The reason is that `a_^n_.` is a pattern with an optional argument and `_.` means that when the optional argument is omitted it should be replaced by the default value globally specified for the function in which it occurs (namely `Power`). You can verify that indeed `Default[Power, 2]` returns `1`.  And you can also `Unprotect[Power]`, set the default value to another constant and retry your example.

Comment: Remove `OneIdentity` attribute form `Power` and try the replacement above... `Unprotect[Power]; ClearAttributes[Power, OneIdentity]; a*b /. a_^n_.*b_^m_. :> {{a, n}, {b, n}}`.

Comment: But you are right in the point that for the replacement I suggested above to work both `OneIdentity` and `Default` matter. It's just that, from my point of view, `OneIdentity` is much more crucial here. It allows expressions without head `Power` at all (before we started talking about any arguments) be matched by patterns that *do* include `Power`. `Default` merely allows  specifying a global default value, as opposed to `Optional` patterns, which define default values locally. The replacement `a*b /. a_^(n_:1)*b_^(m_:1) :> {{a, n}, {b, n}}` doesn't need `Default` but needs `OneIdentity`.